# Открывающееся модальное окно при загрузке страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравсвуйте. Знаю, что этот вопрос уже был, но я не очень разбираюсь в JS. Есть мод окно, которое открывается при нажатии на ссылку. Вопрос, как сделать чтобы оно открывалось сразу при открытии страницы? Мод окно скачал с jqueryui.com. Вот код, который открывает мод окно при нажатии на ссылку:

```
/*Показ поддержавших людей в модальном окне */
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#imgLoad_reply").hide();
$("#us_reply").click(function(){
    var reply_post = $("#reply_post").val();;
    var elem = $("div#dialog-confirm_msg");
    $("#imgLoad_reply").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "reply_us.php",
        dataType: "text",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"reply_post":reply_post},
        success: function(response) {
            $("#imgLoad_reply").hide();
            elem.html(response);
        }
    });
    elem.dialog();
    return false;
});
});
```

Заранее благодарю за отзывчивость.

Comment: вы знаете, что делает `$(document).ready()`? выполняет код при загрузке страницы! теперь думайте!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно помочь удаление строк:

```
$("#us_reply").click(function(){
```

---

```
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо. Все заработало